# web server of airflow is not running

Tags: django, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

m configuring email scheduler in Airflow in Django but its not working.

error in terminal:

```
airflow webserver
[2017-12-29 10:52:17,614] {__init__.py:57} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2017-12-29 10:52:17,734] {driver.py:120} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.5/lib2to3/Grammar.txt
[2017-12-29 10:52:17,765] {driver.py:120} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.5/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
[2017-12-29 10:52:18,354] [8169] {models.py:167} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/hitesh/airflow/dags
Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120
Logfiles: - -
=================================================================            

Error: 'airflow.www.gunicorn_config' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 7):

Airflow (tested v1.8.0) doesn't work with gunicorn 19.4+ for the reasons described here:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/airflow-commits/201708.mbox/%3CJIRA.13063358.1491960900000.100006.1501939203227@Atlassian.JIRA%3E

It should work once you downgrade gunicorn with this command `pip install gunicorn==19.3.0`

Comment: I only ran into this issue when I wasn't using a virtualenv. Without a virtualenv, switching to `gunicorn==19.3.0` didn't work for me on `apache-airflow==1.9.0` and pip 18.1. Depending on where you installed airflow (e.g. w/ a virtual env or without), you might find airflow in a place like: `/home/will/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/www/gunicorn_config.py`. Even running the airflow webserver from within site-packages didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try running `sudo airflow webserver` instead of `airflow webserver`. It helped me with this issue.

Comment: this actually worked but it is interesting why sudo is needed even if you are inside a virtual env.

Comment: Even without virtuaenv also , I was stuck ... Thanks it worked like charm .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Django but encountered the same issue. I got it resolved by applying the changes at this [pr](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/3134) on airflow source code. That is, to replace the command `gunicorn` with its absolute path.

I'm under `Python 3.6.0`, `airflow 1.10.0`, and `gunicorn 19.9.0`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to solve the issue:

- Install guinicorn 19.9.0
- Run:

  whereis gunicorn
- Replace the /usr/bin/gunicorn with a softlink to the recently istalled, in my case:

  `[airflow@foo airflow]$ sudo mv /usr/bin/gunicorn /usr/bin/gunicorn_old
   [airflow@foo airflow]$ sudo ln -s /opt/anaconda3.5/bin/gunicorn /usr/bin/gunicorn
   [airflow@foo airflow]$ /opt/anaconda3.5/bin/gunicorn --version
   gunicorn (version 19.9.0)`
- Start airflow webserver pointing to the 1.10.0, in my case:

  `nohup /opt/anaconda3.5/bin/airflow webserver &
   nohup /opt/anaconda3.5/bin/airflow scheduler &`

This will fix the issue if:

1. whereis guicorn shows different values
2. Linux guicorn executable file is different that the version
   installed in airflow installation.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall package using `sudo pip install airflow==1.8`

It will resolve packages issue.